# Apache mod rewrite http to https with out affecting existing rule

Tags: apache-2.2

I already have a rewrite rule in .htaccess. My old rule replaces all html extensions with php.
My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?set=$1
```

Now we have a SSL so now I want to redirct all url http to https with out affecting my old rule. I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?set=$1RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?set=$1
```

With this, the https redirect is working but my old rule failed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using rewrite for everything, why don't you use redirect to redirect all http connections to https?

```
Redirect / https://your.server.com/
```

Only add this redirect to the http virtual host (I'm assuming you're using virtual hosts to implement the https site).